# jQuery Quick Flip switch back

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins, hover, flip

I'm using the jQuery plugin Quick Flip, but I'm having two issues with one of my pages.

First, I want it to flip when the mouse hovers, which I've been able to do, but I'd also like it to go back to it's original state when you're not hovering.  On the jQuery's forum, others are asking the same question, and the creator says it's possible, but won't provide the code for it.  I've tried different methods, even playing with a setTimeout to force it back, but I keep breaking the code each time so I'm clearly not doing it right.

Second, it sometimes won't flip back at all when you hover again if the panel contains a link.  My example doesn't show this though.  Any idea why that happens?

Here is my example: http://kimkellermedia.com/test3/test2.html

Right now the js is:

```
jQuery(function($){
$('.quickFlip').quickFlip();

for ( var i = 0; i < $.quickFlip.wrappers.length; i++ ) {
    var thisOne = $.quickFlip.wrappers[i];

    $( thisOne.wrapper ).hover( function(ev) {
        var $target = $(ev.target);

        if ( !$target.hasClass('quickFlip') ) $target = $target.parent();

        $target.quickFlipper();

    }, function() {});
}
});
```

Comment: are you using "Quick Flip 2 for jQuery"?

Comment: Please provide fiddle link...

Comment: Thanks for the post Ivan, but, as I said, I already have hover working.  The problem is that it flips, and stays that way until you hover over it again.  I want it to immediately flip back over to it's original state when the mouse is taken off the panel.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Felix answered my question with his comment:

http://jsfiddle.net/Ae9Lx/

Answer (score 2):

If you are using QuickFlip v2.1.1, then you have access to `quickFlipper` which gives you the functionality you want.

From [this blog](http://jonraasch.com/blog/quickflip-2-jquery-plugin), Jon Raasch states that you can have the flip occur on the hover event by using the following code:

> With $.quickFlipper() the flip can be called in the function of your choice. Let's say we want to trigger the flip effect on hover:

```
$('.quickflip-wrapper').hover( function(ev) {
    $(ev.target).quickFlipper();
});
```

Comment: @FelixEbert: Thanks for the awesome demonstration in the jsFiddle!

Comment: hey thanks for the jsFiddle Felix!  That's exactly what I want!

Comment: @coolpup Remember to mark the question as answered if your problem was solved.